# Improving performance of Castle's DynamicProxy?

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm currently trying to implement an AOP system to add automatic audits to decorated attributes of objects (done by an extended version of `INotifyPropertyChanged`). The automatic audit contains the propertyName it's old value and the new value.

I'm currently using Castle's DynamicProxy2 as there are excellent tutorials (namely this one:: http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/04/27/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial.aspx) on how to use the tool. I generate a delegate for each property that is decorated for the type. The expression tree generates something like this:: (note I figure this is easier than pasting my expression tree code as my code relies on a type-safe reflection library and lots of static variables)

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Action`1[Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation]>(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation $invocation) {
    .Block(
        DutchTest.MixinTest $target,
        System.Object $argument,
        System.DateTime $newValue,
        System.DateTime $oldValue) {
        $target = (DutchTest.MixinTest).Call $invocation.get_InvocationTarget();
        $newValue = .Unbox($argument = .Call $invocation.GetArgumentValue(.Default(System.Int32)));
        .If (
            .Call (.Call System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`1[System.DateTime].get_Default()).Equals(
                $oldValue = .Call $target.get_Created(),
                $newValue)
        ) {
            .Default(System.Void)
        } .Else {
            .Block() {
                .Call $invocation.Proceed();
                .Call ($target .As Dutch.Auditing.INotifyAuditedChange).OnPropertyChanged(.New Dutch.Auditing.AuditEventArgs(
                        "Created",
                        (System.Object)$oldValue,
                        $argument))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then have a custom selector which choses the `DelegatedInterceptor` (a class that implements IInterceptor, whose Intercept method is just to invoke the delegate. I also have a custom hook that only chooses the the properties that I plan on delegating (so I avoid the cost of proxying the get method).

Unfortunately, even with all these precautions I am looking at a substantial performance hit on every property set (it takes approximately .4 ticks to do that logic by hand and about 2.2 ticks if I do it with dynamic proxy, 2.8 ticks if I have to mixin the logic for `INotifyAuditedChange` and an event would be raised).  This wouldn't be so bad, but as part of my requirements I am looking at very large amount of objects being modified.

Unfortunately, my plans to use typebuilder failed (it is way too hard to write the code with Reflection.Emit and apparently CompileToMethod cannot be used for instance methods), is there some tricks I am missing to improve the performance of DynamicProxy2?

Comment: Wait, let me make sure I get this right - you're saying that using this adds 5 ticks to your code execution time and that this is too much?

Comment: Per modification.Also, thanks again for that great tutorial, and your awesome work! I agree it sounds absurd, but I'm currently dealing with an operation that can modify about 10000 objects (and potentially many modifications to each) in a transaction scope and anything I can shave off, I'm going to try. I'm trying to make my framework code as lightweight as possible, which is why I'm using codegen with expression trees where applicable to avoid any form of reflection.

Comment: Perhaps you should try PostSharp instead?

Comment: Still waiting on a manager approval for the license, but you're probably right that I'm just being paranoid.